# Segmentation Fault in CPXopenCPLEX

Tags: c++, cplex

I recently reinstalled a 32 bit version of CPLEX on a new Ubuntu 16.04. When I compile the following test program with g++-5.4, it crashes with a segfault.

```
#include "cplex.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int err;

    cout << "CPX_VERSION: " << CPX_VERSION << endl << flush;
    CPXENVptr env_ = CPXopenCPLEX( &err );
    cout << "error: " << err << endl << flush;

    if (env_) {
        cout << "has env" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this with the following call

```
g++ -m32  main.cpp -o main /path/to/cplex/lib/x86_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a -lpthread -I/path/to/cplex/include/ilcplex/
```

The output is

```
CPX_VERSION: 12060300
[1]    21609 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./main
```

Any suggestions of how to fix or debug this are welcome.

**Edit:**
The 64bit version works (without the compiler flag `-m32` and using `x86-64_linux` instead of `x86_linux` in the path to the library, of course). But this doesn't solve my problem, as I need the 32bit version.

**Edit2:** I was able to get a working version on a different computer that also runs on my computer (I think this is a reason to exclude shared libraries as a possible source). I compared the strace output of both binaries and they were almost identical up until the error. The differences were the specific pointer values and the order of lines in the output (probably just an issue with the output buffer and not a real difference).
The working version does two calls to `time(NULL)` at the place were the other version segfaults. Since this is the first call to `time` in the output, this might be the issue.

Comment: "how to debug" - gdb.

Comment: I couldn't get useful output from gdb because CPLEX is closed-source. All I can see from gdb is that the segfault originated in CPXopenCPLEX. @UKMonkey: can you tell me in more detail, how to use gdb in this case?

Comment: Well, options that I can see are:
1. Harass IBM
2. try a 64bit build of cplex & see what happens  (since your machine is 64 bit it may be having issues locating shared libs it wants?)

I would probably consider #1 since there's nothing obviously wrong, although I've not read all the IBM documentation for that function.

Comment: According to IBM the solution is to "reboot the computer". Tried it - didn't help. I'll try downloading the 64bit version. In my case, I particularly need a 32bit build, but if the 64bit version works, this might offer some clue where to look next.

Comment: it might work if you try running it on a 32 bit machine (which would have those libs)

Comment: I don't have access to a 32bit machine, unfortunately. I specifically need a 32bit compile on a 64bit machine. But it looks like this is the problem (see my edit of the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125119/discussion-between-ukmonkey-and-flogo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in the [IBM forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d671bf69-0222-4058-a935-f98c7ce7cba9) and the end result seems to be that this is probably an incompatibility of an old CPLEX version and a new 32-bit binutils version. Since IBM stopped supporting 32-bit builds in the next CPLEX version, there is next to no chance that this bug will ever be fixed.